# Array order changed after multiple array.sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, variables

I have a code to sort array

```
const timeSorted = wheater.list.sort((z,x)=>
{
    return z.dt- x.dt
})
console.log(timeSorted)
```

Output that i get is sorted
but if i add another sort like this

```
const timeSorted = wheater.list.sort((z,x)=>
{
    return z.dt- x.dt
})
const tempSorted = wheater.list.sort((a,b)=>
{
    return a.main.temp - b.main.temp
})
console.log(timeSorted)
```

const timeSorted become tempSorted

How can i fix that?

Comment: please add the array as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz the array is from api . is too long

Comment: not the whole, just two rows with the mentioned properties.

Comment: More: *[mcve]* and [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

The array is sorted *in place*.

In order to not have it changed, you need to create a copy of the previous array using `oldArray.slice()`.

```
const tempSorted = wheater.list.slice().sort((a,b)=>
{
    return a.main.temp - b.main.temp
})
```